# R doesn't find SpatialPoints or SpatialPointsDataFrame

Tags: r, sp

I'm trying to create SpatialPoints objetcs from data frame on R

```
natFPV <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = coordinates(natFPv.per_data[,c(27,28)]),data = natFPv.per_data[,-c(27,28)])
natFPV <- SpatialPoints(coords = coordinates(natFPv.per_data[,c(27,28)]))
```

But getting the error for both:

> Warning: Error in SpatialPoints: could not find function "SpatialPoints"

I'm really don't konw how to deal it.

Comment: Have you imported the library with library(sp)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the library with:

```
library(sp)
```

You need to do this once in each session, unless you [customize your environment](https://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html) to automatically load it each time